# Java DB: No Suitable Driver Found

Tags: java, derby, javadb

Good day!

I know there has been lots of posts for this kind of question, but I've looked at some of them and could not find the answer for my problem since I am using an Embedded Derby.

I am getting this error:

```
##THIS IS GENERATED BY THE METHOD printSQLException shown at the code below
----- SQLException ----- 
SQL State:  08001
Error Code: 0
Message:    No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/recordbookDB

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at recordbook.RecordBook.checkHasAccount(RecordBook.java:71)
    at recordbook.Login.<init>(Login.java:31)
    at recordbook.Login$1.run(Login.java:168)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:226)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:647)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:617)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 6 minutes 16 seconds)
```

The problem is in the connecting to the database part.
This is the part of the code (and the methods) needed to see the problem:

```
public class RecordBook
{
    private String framework = "embedded";
    private String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    private String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
    private Connection conn;

    //this is where everything happens
    public RecordBook()
    {
        //Loading the Driver
        loadDriver();

        //Connecting to the database
        conn = null;
        try
        {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("user","root");
            props.put("password","root");
            String dbName = "//localhost:1527/recordbookDB"; 
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + dbName, props);  //error is here

        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            printSQLException(sqle);
        }
    }

   //BELOW ARE THE METHODS USED ABOVE    
   /**
     * CODE FROM http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html
     */
    private void loadDriver()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            System.out.println("Loaded the appropriate driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
        {
            System.err.println("\nUnable to load the JDBC driver " + driver);
            System.err.println("Please check your CLASSPATH.");
            cnfe.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        catch (InstantiationException ie)
        {
            System.err.println("\nUnable to instantiate the JDBC driver " + driver);
            ie.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException iae)
        {
            System.err.println("\nNot allowed to access the JDBC driver " + driver);
            iae.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    /**
     * CODE FROM http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html
     *
     * @param e the SQLException from which to print details.
     */
    public static void printSQLException(SQLException e)
    {
        // Unwraps the entire exception chain to unveil the real cause of the exception.
        while (e != null)
        {
            System.err.println("\n----- SQLException -----");
            System.err.println("  SQL State:  " + e.getSQLState());
            System.err.println("  Error Code: " + e.getErrorCode());
            System.err.println("  Message:    " + e.getMessage());
            // for stack traces, refer to derby.log or uncomment this:
            //e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            e = e.getNextException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the COMPLETE stack trace, and indicate which statement in your code threw the real exception.  ALso include the source for that statement.

Comment: Where is the source for `recordbook.RecordBook.checkHasAccount()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No suitable driver" usually means that the JDBC URL you've supplied to connect has incorrect syntax.

More details [check out the documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html)

Also check that you have `derby.jar` in your classpath. I would suggest to place `derby.jar` at physical location to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project.Then eclipse will take care for the rest.

Comment: Thanks. I've found the correct URL. The problem is now on the CLASSPATH. It says:

`Unable to load the JDBC driver org.apache.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
Please check your CLASSPATH.`